# Stop a Runnable submitted to ExecutorService

Tags: java, executorservice

I've implemented subscription in my Java app. When new subscriber added, the application creates new task (class which implements `Runnable` to be run in the separate thread) and it is added to the `ExecutorService` like:

```
public void Subscribe()
{
    es_.execute(new Subscriber(this, queueName, handler));
}

//...

private ExecutorService es_;
```

Application may register as many subscribers as you want. Now I want implement something like `Unsubscribe` so every subscriber has an ability to stop the message flow. Here I need a way to stop one of the tasks running in the `ExecutorService`. But I don't know how I can do this.

The `ExecutorService.shutdown()` and its variations are not for me: they terminates all the tasks, I want just terminate one of them. I'm searching for a solution. As simple as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [ExecutorService#submit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) instead of `execute` and use the returned `Future` object to try and cancel the task using [Future#cancel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29)

Example (Assuming `Subscriber` is a `Runnable`):

```
Future<?> future = es_.submit(new Subscriber(this, queueName, handler));
...
future.cancel(true); // true to interrupt if running
```

---

Important note from the comments:

`If your task doesn't honour interrupts and it has already started, it will run to completion.`

Comment: Note: If your task doesn't honour interrupts and it has already started, it will run to completion.

Comment: @PeterLawrey does this mean if your task catches InterruptedException (and doesn't rethrow)?

Comment: @ataulm interrupt() sets a flag. If the code doesn't check the flag or call a method which does, it is just a flag.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I tried removing checks to interrupted flag, just while(true) {..} and it doesn't complete even after calling cancel(). So I guess if the task doesn't honour interrupts, that statement that it will run to completion is false. It just runs indefinitely.

Comment: executorService.submit isnt't throwing an InterruptedException so we cannot catch this

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `ExecutorService.execute(Runnable)`  try using `Future<?> submit(Runnable)`. This method will submit the `Runnable` into the pool for execution and it will return a `Future` object. By doing this you will have references to all subscriber threads.

In order to stop particular thread just use `futureObj.cancel(true)`. This will interrupt the running thread, throwing an `InterruptedException`. The subscriber thread should be coded such way it will stop processing in the case of this exception (for example `Thread.sleep(millis)` with wrapper try / catch block for the whole method).

You cand find more information on the official API:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html