# How to timeout a newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In Android, I'm trying to start a thread that kills itself or is canceled by the executor after some timeout limit for example 20 seconds? So the runnable would only do its work for that many seconds than cancel...

How do I achieve this? I'm currently starting it as the following.

```
Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().schedule(myRunnable, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

My runnable looks like this

```
static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {


     MyRunnable(Helper _helper) {
        helper = _helper;
    }


    public void run() {


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by kills itself?  You could just do a Thread.sleep(20000)

Comment: Do you need to use `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`. Also you want to 'kill' the thread or execute something after 20 seconds?

Comment: i have to use newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor 

Also for example i want to do the runnable task for 20 seconds so if the runnable is printing out helloworld it should do that for 20 seconds straight until 20 seconds are over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop a task that has already been submitted to an `ExecutorService` then you'll need to deal with `Future` objects.

Like this answer:

[Stop a Runnable submitted to ExecutorService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929618/stop-a-runnable-submitted-to-executorservice)

Basically you will `submit` a Runnable and get back a `Future` object that you can use to cancel it.

Specific to your concern: Stop one task in 20 seconds you could use handoff the `Future` object from the first task to another like so:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

// Schedule your audio processing job like normal.
final Future<?> future = executor.submit(new MyAudioProcessingRunnable())

// Schedule the cancelation to happen in 20 seconds.
executor.schedule(new Runnable() {
  if (!future.isCancelled() && !future.isDone()) {
    // Cancel and interrupt any blocking calls.
    future.cancel(true);
  }
}, 20, TimeUnit.Seconds);
```

**IMPORTANT** - You must have code in your `MyAudioProcessingRunnable` to support cancelation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply I may have confused you a bit.

I'm fine with either the runnable killing itself or telling the executor to cancel the thread. Although i want it to be sort of like a count down rather than a sleep. So if the runnable is doing something i want it to do it for X amount of seconds. Then when the countdown goes from X to 0 it should cancel or killitself?

Comment: I see. What would your Thread be doing before being canceled? You'll need to implement some sort of cancelation policy and the implementation depends on what you're doing. Are you doing network IO or something in a for loop?

Comment: Im doing some audio processing i know how to cancel all of the items to avoid memory leaks but the thread itself with a timer is what im confused on

Comment: Is audio processing like a single blocking call like this: `AudioFile processedFile = processAudioFile(rawFile);`?

Comment: Its a non blocking call